# Como puedo hacer un push() al ultimo elemento de un array en un contexto de forEach

Tags: array, foreach, array-bidimensional, push

Estoy trabajando con Firestore de Firebase. Basicamente lo que tengo es un recorrido de un documento de una coleccion a traves de un forEach. Cada documento tiene su propio id (doc.id), y dentro de cada documento hay data (que es un array que lo obtengo con un doc.data()).
Lo que yo quiero hacer es que en base a un array creado fuera del forEach, se vaya agregando por cada documento, primero el id en un elemento, y luego dentro de ese mismo elemento que se agregue el array con la data. La estructura deberia quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
array = 
   0:[
      [0: id
      [1: data[
             prop1: valor1 
             prop2: valor2
          ]
      ] 
  1:[
      [0: id
      [1: data[
             prop1: valor1 
             prop2: valor2
          ]
      ] 
  3:[
      [0: id
      [1: data[
             prop1: valor1 
             prop2: valor2
          ]
      ]
```

el codigo es algo como lo siguiente (esta resumido):

```
 let array = [];  

 querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {          
     array.push(doc.id);              
     array[array.length -1].push(doc.data());        
 });
```

como decia, mi idea es ir agregando el id, y luego la data a ese mismo array del id, es decir al ultimo elemento del array que se va iterando. Como ven use tambien un array[array.length -1] con el que puedo acceder al utimo elemento del array, pero no puedo realizar el push en el mismo. Me tira que .push no es una funcion. Esto si lo hago de esta manera.

Mi pregunta es como podria meter el id y la data dentro de un mismo elemento, por cada vuelta de iteracion del forEach.

Aguardo respuestas,
Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si te entiendo bien, lo que buscas es crear un array de arrays, donde cada elemento tiene el ID y los documentos. A mi entender, lo más fácil que puedes hacer es pushear directamente el array de esta forma:

```
let array = []; 
querySnapshot.forEach( doc => {
    array.push([
        doc.id, doc.data()
    ]);                    
});
```

De esta forma obtendrias la estructura que, entiendo, necesitas.

Comment: Totalmente. Era eso. No se como no se me ocurrió hacerlo asi. Mil gracias!!